# Problem with Tailwind and NexJS render, with some props avatar is hidden

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

have problem with avatar, when I change size (28, 18, 16) - everything is fine.
But when I change size to 24, 22, 20 and other - image is hidden.

Here is my screenshots and code:

**Img Component:**

```
import Image from "next/image";

function Img(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <div className={`relative flex h-[${props.size}px] w-[${props.size}px]`}>
        <Image
          src={
            "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1509967419530-da38b4704bc6?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2095&q=80"
          }
          alt="image"
          fill
          style={{
            objectFit: "cover",
            borderRadius: "999px",
          }}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export { Img };
```

```
import { Img } from "../../elements/common/Img";

export default function AvatarPage() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="flex p-24">
        <Img size={14} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbUnW.png)
[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsPrF.png)

What I do wrong?

[Example 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPToM.png) - if I change size to 38px the image will appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is simply not how Tailwind works.

Tailwind `just-in-time` basically scrapes all of your files (that matches paths in your `content` from `tailwind.config.js`) for **existing** classes and add them to the final distributed CSS. It is totally impossible to create Tailwind dynamic classes via props. You should use  `style=` to add Height.

As a little tip, in the case the possible classes to be generated would be predictable (not [] values, but Tailwind classes), you can make usage of `safelist` [which you can find the documentation here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes).

Comment: I confirm, adding props to the styles solved the problem. These props are passed without problems. I will also study the materials you posted, thanks!

Comment: Here is my code fragment: <div
        className="relative flex cursor-pointer"
        style={{ width: props.size, height: props.size }}
      >